# How to analyze within-subjects repeated measures design with more data for some participants?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures, permutation-test, clustered-standard-errors

I ran a within-subjects study where the study was broken into four time periods and participants were allowed to participate once in each time period. Each time they participated they were exposed to both the treatment and control condition (in a randomized order). In other words, let $Y_{i,j,t}$ be the outcome of participant $i$ from condition $j \in \{0, 1\}$ at time $t$. Then, the data is paired by participant and time period: i.e., if we observe $Y_{i,0,t}$, we also observe $Y_{i,1,t}$.

Originally, I was planning to simply estimate the treatment effect as the difference in mean outcome in the treatment condition and the mean outcome in the control condition: $\bar{Y}_{i,1,t}-\bar{Y}_{i,0,t}$ and calculate p-values using paired permutation tests.

However, this does not account for the fact that some subjects participated only once while others participated in every study time period. How should I account for the correlation in outcomes due to the same subject participating across different study time periods? I was looking into maybe doing a random effects model where each participant has their own associated random effect.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It depends how much data is missing and how many participants have complete or almost complete data, but generally, multilevel regression can handle unbalanced data fairly well.